# Displaying 'No Data' with ListView

Tags: android

I'm using a ListView, and it is not working properly. Please see my code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playerlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/plist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        <TextView
                android:id="@id/android:empty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NO DATA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Well, It works well if the list is empty.

But as the list is short, You can see the 'NO DATA' below the ListView.

If you set the layout_height of the ListView to 'fill_parent', the 'NO DATA' can't appear.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must apply `setEmptyView(View emptyView)` to your listview.

Give your TextView an id, say `emptyView`;

```
TextView emptyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
yourListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

should do the trick.

Hope this helps